# Save queries globally in Navicat, so that they will remain after deleting a database?

Tags: navicat

I often create copies of a database, modifying data, extracting a report and then deleting the database.

If I have had saved the query under that database schema, it seems that they would be lost after deleting the schema.

How can I save queries globally so that they are not associated to a specific schema in Navicat?